# Run method of thread where id stored in map

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, casting, hashmap

Working with Java (latest as of last week), I am trying to call a method of a thread which I have stored in a hashmap. Reason I want to do this (store the thread in a map vs a list) is that I might want to call methods of that thread from multiple places and don't want to have to store data in static variables within MonitorThread to be able to do so.

```
private HashMap<String, Thread> threads = new HashMap<String, Thread>();

MonitorThread t = new MonitorThread();
t.start();
threads.put("monitor", t);

(MonitorThread)(threads.get("monitor")).SendAlert();
```

I get a `cannot resolve SendAlert` error on the last line. Why?

Comment: As an aside, if this `threads` map is going to be accessed from multiple threads (including threads that only read it), you can't use a plain `HashMap` -- it's not thread-safe. You have to wrap it in a `Collections.synchronizedMap`, or use a `ConcurrentHashMap` or some other thread-safe map.

Comment: Thanks yshavit.  This will only be accessed from the main thread so no worries about it... but your observation is well received.  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
((MonitorThread) threads.get("monitor")).SendAlert();
```

Instead.  The `.` operator is higher in the order of operations than a cast.

Also, as @MarcoAcierno indicated in comment below, you can get a `ClassCastException` if you're not careful, so you might:

```
if(threads.get("monitor") instanceof MonitorThread) ((MonitorThread) threads.get("monitor")).SendAlert();
```

Comment: If the collection will contains MonitorThread only is better to change the type of the collection. Or you will get a ClassCastException if you are not careful.

Comment: That did the trick... figured it had to be something simple.. or dumb.  LOL  The map will contain a few different thread classes, so I'll just be careful.  Thank you!

Comment: @Jon if all your threads will contains SendAlert you can create an interface, let your threads implement it and make the collection contains `InterfaceName` so you always sure.